# Haskell AST Annotation with Fix

Tags: haskell, abstract-syntax-tree, recursive-datastructures, fixpoint-combinators

I am working on creating an AST in Haskell. I want to add different annotations, such as types and location information, so I ended up using [fixplate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixplate-0.1.7). However, I can't find any examples online and am having some difficulty.

I've set up my AST as recommended by fixplate (some striped out):

```
data ProgramF a
  = Unary a
          Operator
  | Number Int
  | Let { bindings :: [(Identifier, a)]
        , body :: a }

type Program = Mu ProgramF
```

Next to add a label I created another type, and a function to add labels based on a tree traversal.

```
type LabelProgram = Attr ProgramF PLabel

labelProgram :: Program -> LabelProgram
labelProgram =
  annMap (PLabel . show . fst) . (snd . synthAccumL (\i x -> (i + 1, (i, x))) 0)
```

However, beyond this I am running into some issues. For example, I am trying to write a function that does some transformation on the AST. Because it requires a label to function, I've made the type `LabelProgram -> Program`, but I think I am doing something wrong here. Below is a snippet of part of the function (one of the simpler parts):

```
toANF :: LabelProgram -> Program
toANF (Fix (Ann label (Let {bindings, body}))) = Fix $ Let bindingANF nbody
  where
    bindingANF = map (\(i, e) -> (i, toANF e)) bindings
    nbody = toANF body
```

I feel like I am working at the wrong level of abstraction here. Should I be explicitly matching against `Fix Ann ...` and returning `Fix ...` like this, or am I utilizing fixplate wrong?

Additionally, I am concerned about how to generalize functions. How can I make my functions work for `Program`s, `LabelProgram`s, and `TypeProgram`s generically?

Comment: `Attr f a` is just a synonym for `Mu (Ann f a)`, so you can use the cornucopia of traversals available in fixplate. `toANF` is essentially `forget`, but reading your intents, you don't want to remove the labels from your AST, do you? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/fixplate-0.1.7/docs/Data-Generics-Fixplate-Traversals.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Edit:* Add an example of a function for `ProgramF`s with generic annotations.

Yes, at least in the case of `toANF`, you're using it wrong.

In `toANF`, note that your `Let bindingANF nbody` and the companion definitions of `bindingANF` and `nbody` are just a reimplementation of `fmap toANF` for the specific constructor `Let`.

That is, if you derive a `Functor` instance for your `ProgramF`, then you can re-write your `toANF` snippet as:

```
toANF :: LabelProgram -> Program
toANF (Fix (Ann label l@(Let _ _))) = Fix (fmap toANF l)
```

If `toANF` is *just* stripping labels, then this definition works for all constructors and not just `Let`, so you can drop the pattern:

```
toANF :: LabelProgram -> Program
toANF (Fix (Ann label l)) = Fix (fmap toANF l)
```

and now, as per @Regis_Kuckaertz's comment, you've just re-implemented `forget` which is defined as:

```
forget = Fix . fmap forget . unAnn . unFix
```

With respect to writing functions that work generically on `Program`, `LabelProgram`, etc., I think it makes more sense to write functions generic in a (single) annotation:

```
foo :: Attr ProgramF a -> Attr ProgramF a
```

and, if you *really* need to apply them to the unannotated program, define:

```
type ProgramU = Attr ProgramF ()
```

where the "U" in `ProgramU` stands for "unit".  Obviously, you can easily write translators to work with `Program`s as `ProgramU`s if really needed:

```
toU :: Functor f => Mu f -> Attr f ()
toU = synthetise (const ())

fromU :: Functor f => Attr f () -> Mu f
fromU = forget

mapU :: (Functor f) => (Attr f () -> Attr f ()) -> Mu f -> Mu f
mapU f = fromU . f . toU

foo' :: Mu ProgramF -> Mu ProgramF
foo' = mapU foo
```

As a concrete -- if stupid -- example, here's a function that separates `Let`s with multiple bindings into nested `Let`s with singleton bindings (and so breaks mutually recursive bindings in the `Program` language).  It assumes that the annotation on a multi-binding `Let` will be copied to each of the resulting singleton `Let`s:

```
splitBindings :: Attr ProgramF a -> Attr ProgramF a
splitBindings (Fix (Ann a (Let (x:y:xs) e)))
  = Fix (Ann a (Let [x] (splitBindings (Fix (Ann a (Let (y:xs) e))))))
splitBindings (Fix e) = Fix (fmap splitBindings e)
```

It can be applied to an example `Program`:

```
testprog :: Program
testprog = Fix $ Unary (Fix $ Let [(Identifier "x", Fix $ Number 1), 
                                   (Identifier "y", Fix $ Number 2)] 
                                  (Fix $ Unary (Fix $ Number 3) NegOp))
                       NegOp
```

like so:

```
> mapU splitBindings testprog
Fix (Unary (Fix (Let {bindings = [(Identifier "x",Fix (Number 1))],
body = Fix (Let {bindings = [(Identifier "y",Fix (Number 2))], 
body = Fix (Unary (Fix (Number 3)) NegOp)})})) NegOp)
>
```

Here's my full working example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Data.Generics.Fixplate

data Identifier = Identifier String deriving (Show)
data PLabel = PLabel deriving (Show)
data Operator = NegOp deriving (Show)

data ProgramF a
  = Unary a
          Operator
  | Number Int
  | Let { bindings :: [(Identifier, a)]
        , body :: a }
  deriving (Show, Functor)
instance ShowF ProgramF where showsPrecF = showsPrec

type Program = Mu ProgramF
type LabelProgram = Attr ProgramF PLabel

splitBindings :: Attr ProgramF a -> Attr ProgramF a
splitBindings (Fix (Ann a (Let (x:y:xs) e)))
  = Fix (Ann a (Let [x] (splitBindings (Fix (Ann a (Let (y:xs) e))))))
splitBindings (Fix e) = Fix (fmap splitBindings e)

toU :: Functor f => Mu f -> Attr f ()
toU = synthetise (const ())

fromU :: Functor f => Attr f () -> Mu f
fromU = forget

mapU :: (Functor f) => (Attr f () -> Attr f ()) -> Mu f -> Mu f
mapU f = fromU . f . toU

testprog :: Program
testprog = Fix $ Unary (Fix $ Let [(Identifier "x", Fix $ Number 1), 
                                   (Identifier "y", Fix $ Number 2)] 
                                  (Fix $ Unary (Fix $ Number 3) NegOp))
                       NegOp

main :: IO ()
main = print $ mapU splitBindings testprog
```